# Stuck on Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I want the query to return all items that match my search condition, but when the table returns there are duplicates of the same item.

```
SELECT i.*
FROM Item i, Lead_Singer s
WHERE i.category = '' OR i.title = 'test 2 CD' OR (s.name = '' AND i.upc = s.upc);
```

The results would be something like

10  test 2 CD   CD  Rock    Easy Entertainment  2013    19.99   11

10  test 2 CD   CD  Rock    Easy Entertainment  2013    19.99   11

10  test 2 CD   CD  Rock    Easy Entertainment  2013    19.99   11

10  test 2 CD   CD  Rock    Easy Entertainment  2013    19.99   11

Where all of the items fitting the description will be returned 4 times.

My tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE item(
upc char(30) not null,
Title char(30) not null,
Type enum("CD" , "DVD") not null,
Category enum("Rock", "Pop", "Rap", "Country", "Classical", "New age", "Instrumental") not null,
Company char(30) not null, 
Year year not null,
Price char(30) not null, 
Stock char(30) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(upc));

CREATE TABLE Lead_Singer(
upc char(30) not null, 
Name char(30) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(upc, name));

ALTER TABLE lead_singer
ADD FOREIGN KEY(upc) REFERENCES item(upc);
```

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A Select distinct only gives you different results

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.*
FROM Item i, Lead_Singer s
WHERE i.category = '' OR i.title = 'test 2 CD' OR (s.name = '' AND i.upc = s.upc);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my first time working with mysql so I'm learning as I go :P